# How to fix - 'createCipherIv' of crypto-browserify(react-native-crypto) is always using and returning 16 bytes auth tag for 'aes-256-gcm'?

Tags: node.js, react-native, cryptojs, aes-gcm

During `createCipheriv()`, the option to set the tag length is not being considered in `crypto-browserify/react-native-crypto`.

I have correctly followed the steps where to make `crypto` compatible with `react native` and I'm able to build the app without any issue, however, the `authTagLength` option is ignored in `crypto-browserify/react-native-crypto` implementations.

```
     const encryptedGcmBuffer = crypto.createCipheriv('aes-256-gcm', this.aesKey, aesGcmIvAdd, {
        authTagLength: 4,
    });
    /* Get the auth Tag */
    encryptedGcmBuffer.getAuthTag()
```

This code snippet uses and returns `auth` tag length as 4 bytes in `Node.js` for `aes gcm` encryption, while in react native it's always using 16 bytes.

Is there a way we can fix this inconsitency?

Answer (score 0):

The current implementation of createCipheriv in crypto-browserify doesn't use the `options` 4th argument.
https://github.com/crypto-browserify/browserify-aes/blob/master/encrypter.js#L86

authTagLength should be handled here, but it seems unsupported for now.